# Host virtual box hard disk on another partition

Tags: virtualbox

When i create a virtual drive using virtualbox, the space needed is used from the partition i have installed ubuntu on. Can i change this so that i can use one of my other mounted partitions for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Open VirtualBox main window, go to `File, Preferences` and change the `Default Machine Folder` to the folder/partition you want.